# How to find average value of counted data in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to find an average value between each window frame of the amount of similar system by using Spark structured streaming (The concept is similar to Rolling average). However, structured streaming doesn't allow us to count a similar column and find an average based on that counted value, it will have an error which states that

```
Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets
```

```
Input 
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              window|              system|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[2019-06-21 09:23...|A                   |    
|[2019-06-21 09:23...|A                   |  
|[2019-06-21 09:24...|A                   |  
|[2019-06-21 09:24...|B                   |  
|[2019-06-21 09:24...|B                   | 
|[2019-06-21 09:25...|C                   |
+--------------------+--------------------+
Output
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+
|              window|              system|count|avg  |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+
|[2019-06-21 09:23...|A                   |    2|    2|
|[2019-06-21 09:24...|A                   |    1|  1.5|
|[2019-06-21 09:24...|B                   |    2|    2|
|[2019-06-21 09:25...|C                   |    1|    1|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

I already tried to collect it in HDFS and consume it again in order to do another aggregation separately (which is not the preferred solution cause it will waste a lot of time and storage) but it still has a problem with 
'window.start' while trying to apply a watermark.

Here's the schema

```
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = true)
```

```py
avg_data=raw_data\
.withWatermark("window.start", "1 minute")\
.groupBy("system")\
.agg(avg("count").alias("avg"))
```

```
 An error occurred while calling o667.withWatermark.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: makeCopy, tree:
'EventTimeWatermark 'window.start, interval 1 minutes
```

Since I do it in Structured streaming so Window will not be supported in this case since

```
Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;
```

Here's the code when I group/count similar subject.

```py
groupped_data=raw_data\
.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minute")\
.groupBy(window('timestamp', "1 minute", "1 minute"),"system")\
.agg(count("system").alias("count"))\
```

Comment: Can you include the code that leads to the error? I don't seem to understand _"doesn't allow us to count a similar column and find an average based on that counted value"_.